# Can we install mongo db on ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: mongodb

I wanted to install mongo db on my ubuntu 19.10 but it says that we can only use the LTS versions of it.

So is there a way that I can use it on 19.10.

Comment: `sudo add-apt-repository universe; sudo apt install mongodb-server`

Answer (score 2):

I thought that what was in the description of the MongoDB (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) was only for Ubuntu LTS but actually you can do the same steps with the an Ubunto 19:10.

Just use the 18:04 LTS repository (the link is on the page). I think that the repositories are the place in where they like to do the support for Ubuntu or something.

But before you do anything with the commands below, make sure you don't have any MongoDB package install (that is because you DO can install MongoDB with the Ubuntu repositories but they are way outdated (they give you MongoDB 3.6 when the update version is 4.2) try using `mongod --version` and `mongo --version` to see if you have any of this things install (they are the way of using mongodb) if it said that you have some packages or the whole mongod and mongo installed, try removing them with `sudo apt-get remove` plus the name of the package, just type `sudo apt-get remove mongo and press tab` and you'll see all the packages related to MongoDB, erase them one by one).

> So, first open the terminal `alt+ctrl+t`. Then use this `wget -qO -
>   https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.2.asc | sudo apt-key add
>   -` to import the public key used by the package management system.
>   However, if you receive an error indicating that gnupg is not installed, you can installed with this command `sudo apt-get install gnupg`, then retry `wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.2.asc | sudo apt-key add -` and after that, since you're using Ubuntu 19:10, you can use the Ubuntu 18:04 LTS Bionic repository with this command: `echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.2 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.2.list` reload the package with `sudo apt-get update` and finally install them with this command `sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org` (that's for the latest version of MongoDB, for an specific version of MongoDB do something like this `sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org=4.2.6 mongodb-org-server=4.2.6 mongodb-org-shell=4.2.6 mongodb-org-mongos=4.2.6 mongodb-org-tools=4.2.6` with the name of the specific version in each part of that command).
>   And you did it, you installed, I hope it helped you.